# Shiny DT unable to add buttons to download as csv/excel

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Having trouble adding buttons for "download as csv/excel" to my Shiny app DataTable section.
It seems that as my "Data" is queried from redshift, it doesn't recognize it as a data frame.

Error thrown:
**'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)**

From this document it seems to return it as a data frame which would contradict the error message. Any idea how I could fix this and get the buttons to work?

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$executeSQL, {
    if (input$selection == "CL7D") {
      output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({ 
        dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from dummy")
        extensions = "Buttons" 
        options = list(paging = TRUE,
                       scrollX=TRUE, 
                       searching = TRUE,
                       ordering = TRUE,
                       dom = 'Bfrtip',
                       buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                       pageLength=5, 
                       lengthMenu=c(3,5,10) )
      })
    }
    
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first argument to `renderDataTable` is indeed an expression, as it should be, but ... your expression is not doing much.

1. First, it retrieves some data from `dbGetQuery`, but since it isn't stored anywhere, it is immediately lost.
2. Then it creates a local variable named `extensions` and assigned the value `"Buttons"`.
3. Last, it creates a local variable named `options` that is `list(..)`.

Since the default behavior in R is for an expression with `{ ... }` is for it to "return" the last expression within it, that means that it doesn't return the value from `dbGetQuery`, it doesn't return `extensions`, it instead returns the value of `options`, which is not 2-dimensional.

Perhaps you meant:

```r
  observeEvent(input$executeSQL, {
    if (input$selection == "CL7D") {
      output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(        # remove the '{'
        dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from dummy"),   # add a ','
        extensions = "Buttons",                   # add a ','
        options = list(paging = TRUE,
                       scrollX=TRUE, 
                       searching = TRUE,
                       ordering = TRUE,
                       dom = 'Bfrtip',
                       buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                       pageLength=5, 
                       lengthMenu=c(3,5,10) )
      )                                            # remove the '}'
    }
    
  })
```

Side notes:

1. I tend to prefer to keep data-creating/querying actions as simple `reactive` components that then may be used elsewhere. For example, let's say you wanted a banner at top of your shiny app to display the number of rows returned. With your current code, you would need to run `dbGetQuery` *twice*.

   Instead, make it reactive and then use it later; that way, if you need to use the data for any other component in your shiny app, you'll have it available separately.

   ```r
     mydata <- eventReactive(input$executeSQL, {
       dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from dummy")
     })
     observeEvent(mydata(), {
       if (input$selection == "CL7D") {
         output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(
           mydata(),
           extensions = "Buttons",
           options = list(paging = TRUE,
                          scrollX=TRUE, 
                          searching = TRUE,
                          ordering = TRUE,
                          dom = 'Bfrtip',
                          buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                          pageLength=5, 
                          lengthMenu=c(3,5,10) )
         )
       }

     })
   ```
2. I've yet to see one working example of `shiny` where having a reactive component nested within another made sense. I have not tested your code here (lacking data and ui and such), but I suspect that your code would operate better, more-cleanly as

   ```r
     mydata <- eventReactive(input$executeSQL, {
       dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from dummy")
     })
     output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable(
       if (input$selection == "CL7D") mydata(),
       extensions = "Buttons",
       options = list(paging = TRUE,
                          scrollX=TRUE, 
                          searching = TRUE,
                          ordering = TRUE,
                          dom = 'Bfrtip',
                          buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                          pageLength=5, 
                          lengthMenu=c(3,5,10) )
         )
   ```

   If that doesn't work, move the `if` conditional out,

   ```r
     mydata <- eventReactive(input$executeSQL, {
       dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from dummy")
     })
     data_CL7D <- reactive({
       if (input$selection == "CL7D") mydata()
     })
     output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable(
       data_CL7D(),
       extensions = "Buttons",
       options = list(paging = TRUE,
                          scrollX=TRUE, 
                          searching = TRUE,
                          ordering = TRUE,
                          dom = 'Bfrtip',
                          buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                          pageLength=5, 
                          lengthMenu=c(3,5,10) )
         )
   ```